# dynamically creating select elements and populating options from sharepoint list

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sharepoint

The code I wrote works, but it could be better.  I am writing out the same function three times, one for each of the combo box elements.  I am stuck on how to make this more efficient.  I have looked at creating an object and putting each of the variables in an array, but I was not able to successfully get it working.

```
    var csCategory = <%=csCategoryArray%>,
        csKeyword = <%=csKeywordArray%>,
        csEntity = <%=csEntityArray%>;

 addOption = function (selectbox, text, value) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}

$(function () {
    // Temp test stuff to populate option list
    var selectObj = document.getElementById("combobox1")
    if (selectObj) {
        for (var i=0; i < csCategory.length;++i){    
            addOption(selectObj, csCategory[i], csCategory[i]);
        }
    }
}); 

$(function () {
    // Temp test stuff to populate option list
    var selectObj = document.getElementById("combobox2")
    if (selectObj) {
        for (var i=0; i < csKeyword.length;++i){    
            addOption(selectObj, csKeyword[i], csKeyword[i]);
        }
    }
});  

$(function () {
    // Temp test stuff to populate option list
    var selectObj = document.getElementById("combobox3")
    if (selectObj) {
        for (var i=0; i < csEntity.length;++i){    
            addOption(selectObj, csEntity[i], csEntity[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious first step is to refactor out the shared code. So:

```
$(function () {
  // Temp test stuff to populate option list
  var selectObj = document.getElementById("combobox2")
  if (selectObj) {
    for (var i=0; i < csKeyword.length;++i){    
        addOption(selectObj, csKeyword[i], csKeyword[i]);
    }
  }
});  

( ... etc ... )
```

becomes:

```
function populate(id, collection) {
  var selectObj = document.getElementById(id)
  if (selectObj) {
    for (var i=0; i < collection.length;++i){    
        addOption(selectObj, collection[i], collection[i]);
    }
  }
}

$(function () {
  populate ("combobox1", csCategory);
  populate ("combobox2", csKeyword);
  populate ("combobox3", csEntity);
});
```

I can't see any significant advantage *at this stage* of putting `combobox1` and its siblings into an array, but it may be worthwhile revisiting this code if more comboboxes are added in the future.

Comment: I thought getElementById() didn't work in SharePoint because how it prefixes the containers onto the ID of contained elements?