# Dynamic textboxes with dropdownlist populated by database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a project where I need to provide functionality that allows a user to click a button (1 or more times) to dynamically add 2 textboxes with labels and a dropdownlist populated by a database call each time the button in clicked.

At first I was using jquery to add the 2 textboxes with labels but just had the requirement to add the dropdown populated by a database call.

I was using the following code for the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            var field = $("#field").val();
            var input = "<input name='titles' id='field' type='text' />";
            var input2 = "<textarea name='descriptions' id='field' rows='8' columns='80' />";
            var newRow = "<tr><td>" + field + "</td><td>" + input + "</td><td>" + input2 + "</td></tr>";
            var newRow2 = "<br /><label>Additional Issue: </label><br /><input type='text' size='50' name='addIssue' id='field' value='' /><br /><br /><label>Description:</label><br /><textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='addProblem' id='field' ></textarea><br /><br />"
            $('#controls').append(newRow2);
        });
    });
</script>
```

That works great. However, I'm struggling with the best way to add in the dropdown, and it can be server side or clientside. I really haven't created asp.net controls dynamically, but I think that would be the way to go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Best way to create it at client side or from server side?

Comment: Either way to be honest. I'm really just looking for the best solution

Comment: Well if you don't need the data at server side and they will be just at client side, then doing it at client side would be best. But if you want to access it at server side, then creating from asp using an ajax call will be the best approach. All depends on your need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, to fit in with the rest of your design, you should probably just do it client side. You can create a select input pretty much just like you're doing your text inputs, then add options using AJAX call to a JSON web method. There are a lot of examples of this online, but [here's one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae11ac/dynamically-dropdownlist-using-ajax/) and [here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645896/dynamically-creating-select-elements-and-populating-options-from-sharepoint-list). And [here's a third](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/).

Comment: Its must be a comment because your answer solely just give the references rather than a proper solution. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-)

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks so much!